# Mary as the Queen of heaven

Tags: catholicism, church-history, virgin-mary

The Pope Pius XII in the encyclical AD CAELI REGINAM recognizes Mary as the "queen of heaven", although historically she was already known that way. If the Pope knows the Bible, why not distance himself in his encyclical from the references to the "queen of heaven" found in Jeremiah chapter 7 and 44?

Comment: The encyclicals had not cited any reference to the Book of Jeremiah, so its baseless to make a comparison.

Comment: That is may point, why the encyclicals did not mention Jeremiah knowing that there is an instance where the title is mentioned?

Answer (score 5):

Because it's obvious to most people that Jeremiah 7 is referring to *a false pagan deity*, and *not* the blessed virgin Mary. **To associate the two is to give credence to the idea that they are somehow related, which they obviously aren't.** Highly venerating a female whom you believe God has made Queen of His Kingdom (something theoretically very possible, and easy for God; and queens and kings are venerated) is not 'cancelled' or 'forbidden' by the fact that pagans previously, or before that point,  gave the same title or honorific or role to a false deity. E.g. if pagans viewed a particular god (like Baal, which means Lord) as Lord, it doesn't mean there is not a true lord (God or man), just that pagans used the same title or honorific for their false deity—stole it, or used it wrongly. Pagans getting to 'copyright' certain dates or names for things and people or whatever else is just a ridiculous concept.

If Jeremiah wasn't speaking of the blessed virgin Mary, then it's just not relevant to discuss. And we know he wasn't because the virgin Mary didn't exist yet for another 640 years or so, but Jeremiah was speaking of something current in his day, and also of something concerning worship of a false deity, not the blessed woman Christians have always considered the greatest of the saints by virtue of being the mother of not only the Messiah, but the Messiah who was and is God, and of whom she was and is the mother to this day.

Consider an analogy. Imagine there was a pagan deity pagans called "the King of Heaven." It's almost impossible none such false deity was worshiped under this title. Does God approve of that false deity? I'd like to think so. And yet how is God still the King of Heaven? He is because He actually is, and this false deity is not.

It's very simple, really.

Comment: You neglect to also consider that Jeremiah is speaking of an idoltatrous _concept_ which, in his day, was occupied by a false deity and in our day is also occupied by an idolatrous misconception : that the _concept_ of a 'heavenly queen' is consistent with both Jeremiah's time and our own.

Comment: **King of Heaven** is a Biblical title for God, but _"Queen of Heaven"_ is an extra-Biblical name for Mary, and ascribe to her after primitive Christianity

Comment: @wildmangrove Yes, my point is that if pagans worshipped a 'king of heaven' is entirely irrelevant to God's being called King of heaven. The pagans are (1) unjustly ascribing someone else's title to a false god (2) worshipping a false god. Similarly, if pagans considered that there exists a female deity, and they called her the 'queen of heaven' (something quite expected of a deity), it doesn't mean that Mary can't be the true queen of heaven in the true sense, and is not properly so called. It just doesn't logically follow.

Comment: @NigelJ Does my answer raise doubts as to whether Jeremiah was doing what he was obviously doing: condemning idolatry here?

Comment: @wildmangrove that's not necessarily the way the Catholic Church sees things, and the question requires that perspective.

Comment: @MattGutting No, because that is my personal belief. My question go more along the route that "it is strange not to quote the Book of Jeremiah." For example, if a group in the western world begin to use the swastika, a symbol adopted (not created) by the Nazi party (and use in many other cultures and religions), but if this group does not recognize that and do not distance themselves from them. (1) They are oblivious the history of WW2 or (2) they are nazis

Comment: @wildmangrove "As indicated in the previous comment, the problem is with the use of extra-biblical names" Not if you're asking Catholics: most of us wouldn't consider it logical to expect all true things that people could be called, or all true things that could be said about people is said in Scripture. It's actually very bizarre in fact.

Comment: @wildmangrove It comes down to this: is Mary queen? according to the Church, yes. Is Jesus' kingdom of heaven or earth? "My kingdom is not of this world." It's as simple as that. If previous pagans called their made up deities "queen" and specifically "of heaven," this does nothing to invalidate the already established facts about Mary. They were wrong to (1) have false deities (2) call them what they were not on top of that. But CHRISTIANS are not wrong in calling someone who truly is such, such. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @SolaGratia Well it is a bizarre fact, but an interisting point, I will delete my comment about extra-biblical names. I'm not saying that Mary should not be name like that because some pagan deity in the past. What I'm arguing is because the title was used for a pagan deity in the past _in the Bible_ **it should be acknowledge** (like my example of the swastika), so for me is odd that it isn't